# How to calculate the expected number of times a specific pattern appears in a set of n numbers of Bernouilli trials?

Tags: probability

Let's consider a set of `n` Bernouilli trials of parameter `p` $\text{(O1,...,On)}$. Let's name the two possible outcomes as `+` and `-`. How to calculate the expected number of times we will match a pattern of `k` outcomes with `k < n` ? For instance how many times the pattern $\text{(+,-,+)}$ will appear if we perform 20 Bernouilli trials in a row ? What's the name of probability law for this experience ?

Comment: Does $+-+-+$ count as two appearances of $+-+$?  If so, the answer to your example is $18p^2(1-p)$ and the generalisation is obvious, by [linearity of expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity)

Comment: well I'm not sure if I should count it as two appearances. My final goal is to test wether a pattern occurs randomly or not in times series so maybe I will have to work out a P-value. Thanks for the formula I'll try to think of what you're saying about linearity of expectation until I get a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use $1,0$ instead of $+,-$, with $1$ having probability $p$.

Let $\mathbf{1}_i(k)$ be the indicator on the event that pattern $k$ appears at position $i$. So for example if you see $11011$, and your pattern is $k=11$ then it appears at $i=1$ and $i=4$. Then let $X_n$ be the number of occurances of your pattern for $n$ throws, and also define $|k|$ to be the length of your pattern (if $k=11$ then $|k|=2$). We get that:

$$X_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-|k|}\mathbf{1}_i(k).$$

By linearity of expectation, $E[X_n]=\sum_{i=1}^{n-|k|}E[\mathbf{1}_i(k)]$, and $E[\mathbf{1}_i(k)]=P(k)$, where $P(k)$ is of the form $p^{k_1}(1-p)^{k_0}$, where $k_1$ is the number of 1's in $k$ and $k_0$ is the number of $0$'s, with $k_1+k_0=|k|$,  so

$$E[X_n]=(n-|k|)p^{k_1}(1-p)^{|k|-k_1}.$$

Comment: soz for the edit $\mathbf{1}_i(k)$ equals 1 or 0 that's why you call it indicator and not index edit : ok got it very nice formalism ty